Resetting values containing comments in new line to empty list also modifies other values. Reloading resulting yaml errors
This is the yaml file I am loading
key1:
  # comment1
  - t1: t_value
    u1: u_value
  - t2: t_value
    u2: u_value
key2:
  # comment2
  key21:
    k1: 0.1
    k2: 0.2
    k3: 0.6

I am running the code below
import ruamel.yaml as ruamel

_ruamel = ruamel.YAML()
_ruamel.preserve_quotes = True
_ruamel.indent(mapping=2, sequence=4, offset=2)
_ruamel.width = 120

with open('test.yml') as f:
    data = f.read()
    data = _ruamel.load(data.encode())

data['key1'] = []
with open('test.yml', 'w') as f:
    _ruamel.dump(data, f)


The resulting output is
key1:
  # comment1
    []
key2:
  # comment2
  key21: k1: 0.1
    k2: 0.2
    k3: 0.6

The key k1 is moved to one line up.
When I try to run the same code again it results in the following error
ruamel.yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here
  in "<byte string>", line 6, column 12:
      key21: k1: 0.1
               ^ (line: 6)

I would expect it to not error when reloading the modified file. Nor should it change other keys that were not modified.

You put a comment between a key and its value, that is currently not always supported, a known issue that still has not been fixed.\ Apart from that the officially recommended extension for files containing YAML documents has been .yaml since at least Sept 2006 (the YML format is an XML derivative).

Understood. Just also wanted to clarify if I were to put the comment in the same line key1: #comment1 followed by values everything works well as expected
